# How to calculate tables with percentages

Tags: pivot-table, percentage, qliksense

I am having trouble creating a table in qliksense expressed in percentages. My raw data are like the following:

raw data:
[image: raw data]

I want to create a table that shows the number of new people per year among the different ages, both in absolute values and in percentage (of the total new students of each year).
I am using the following code to calculate the absolute value

```
Count(IF(NUM=1 and [NEW STUDENT]='YES', ((NAME))))
```

But I am really having trouble to calculate the same value in percentage. I studied the function TOTAL, but it does not work with IFS, so I tried with something like this after navigating on different forums

```
Count(IF(NUM=1 and [NEW STUDENT]='YES', ((NAME))))
/
Count(TOTAL {<[NEW STUDENT] = {'YES'}>} {<[NUM] = {1}>}  NAME)
```

But it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

please try following expression in table/chart:

```
Count({<[NEW STUDENT]={'YES'}, [NUM]={1}>}  NAME)
/
Count({<[NEW STUDENT]={'YES'}, [NUM]={1}, [NAME]= >}  NAME)
```

Please provide desired outcome table from included sample data so I can test it (there is also ready options like "show in percent" which can be used)